# Using partitioned table, and dealing with auto_increment PK

Tags: mysql, innodb, partitioning, primary-key, mysql-5.6

I have a big table (>100 million rows) that tracks user's activities. It has an ID, which is PK and has `auto_increment` property. This is the only unique key. Table also has userid and datetime column.

I want to partition the table by datetime, but mysql mandates that

```
every unique key on the table must use every column in the table's partitioning expression
```

So, that means I have to make PK consisting of (ID, datetime).

My concern is, ID column is no longer a unique entity. While the ID is always created automatically, there's no prevention against a bad code generating ID of its own and mess up the uniqueness of the column.

What is the common practice to rectify this situation?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Consider also make the pk `(datetime, id)`

Comment: But that still doesn't solve my concern of preventing 2 records with same id value, right?

Comment: no, it doesn't. The restriction in MySQL's partitioning is there so every search with any primary or unique key should be able to search only one partition. So, if you want to partition by date, then your searches should not use ID alone but date+id or just date. The auto_increment will prevent any duplicates anyway (unless there are manual inserts or updates.) But the uniqueness on `(id)` will not be not strictly enforced, true.

Comment: You can still add a non-unique index on `(id, datetime)` so searching by id only is fast.

Comment: @ypercube thanks for your input. Yeah I'm probably being paranoid but then again you never know what crazy, umm, _creative_ idea devs might think of. I just thought many people would be confronted with this dilemma and I was wondering if there's a common fix. (I once used triggers  but it wasn't elegant)

Comment: Your line of thinking is good, you are not paranoid. More options: manual partitioning (requires more maintenance), stored procedures (bad performance), application-level uuid generator.